# F# JSON connected task

Tags: .net, json, f#, functional-programming

Suppose I have the following code for my custom union:

```
type JSON =
| Object of (string * JSON) list
| Array of JSON list
| Number of double
| Boolean of bool
| Null
| String of string
```

How can I implement the function 'find the sum of all numbers in JSON object'? `let summarizer (tree : JSON) : int`

It should recursively traverse the JSON tree and return as a result the sum of all numbers in JSON object.

Comment: Before I answer this: is this homework that you need to do yourself? In other words, are you looking for hints from which you can work out the answer yourself, or for a more complete answer?

Comment: @rmunn anything. Of course, complete answer would be great.

Comment: Just be advised that if this *is* homework, you should note that you got help from StackOverflow, and reference this question. Most professors are perfectly okay with you getting help if you acknowledge it, but submitting someone else's code while pretending that it's your own would be cheating, and would have severe consequences. If this isn't homework and you're just trying to learn F# techniques for yourself, then ignore this comment. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should start by considering each individual case of the `JSON` type, and deciding how that case would contribute to the sum. I'll go from bottom to top since the top cases are the harder ones:

- `String` - would add 0.0 to the sum.
- `Null` - would add 0.0 to the sum.
- `Boolean` - would add 0.0 to the sum.
- `Number` - would add itself to the sum.
- `Array` - Go through the individual `JSON` items in the array, and calculate each of their individual sums. All those sums added together get added to the running total sum.
- `Object` - Go through the pairs, and in each pair, the second item is a JSON object that would have a sum. Sum all those up, and you get a number to add to the sum.

And now we have the function almost written for us already!

```
let rec sumOfJson = function
    | Object list -> List.sumBy (snd >> sumOfJson) list
    | Array list -> List.sumBy sumOfJson list
    | Number n -> n
    | Boolean _
    | Null
    | String _ -> 0.0
```

If you don't understand the `snd >> sumOfJson` part, that's exactly equivalent to `fun x -> x |> snd |> sumOfJson`. Here, `x` is a `string * JSON` pair, so that's equivalent to `fun (_, json) -> sumOfJson json`.